# Click event on <tabset> is not fired

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to call an event on tab selection but it is not get fired
i am new in Angular please find below code which on i have tried i know there is some mistake i am doing
but i am not getting out of it

typescript Code in TS File

```
SelectedTabConcernGrid(selectedGrid) {
    debugger;
    this._selectedGrid=selectedGrid;
}
```

html file code

```
<tabset>
    <tab (click)="SelectedTabConcernGrid(1)" heading="All Concern Details">
        <app-all-concern-grid [ConcernGrid]="ConcernGrid"></app-all-concern-grid>
    </tab>
    <tab (click)="SelectedTabConcernGrid(2)" heading="Reassigned To CC Concern Details">
        <div class="card" style="padding: 5px;padding-top: 10px;" >
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: Which library are you using for tabset?

Comment: i am using bootstrap tabset tab

Comment: What is name of your thirdparty? Do you mean the tabset of ng-bootstrap?